# tomcat server getting hanged randomly(no logs come) and after Ctrl+c it starts working and even logs atart coming

Tags: java, tomcat

I have deployed my application on tomcat server, but randomly my server stops giving the logs and intermittently the application hangs but after doing Ctrl+c the logs again start coming and application starts working. The logs are as:

```
2017-04-13 12:50:42,711 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
2017-04-13 12:50:42,711 WARN  - SqlExceptionHelper         - SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
2017-04-13 12:50:42,711 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - IO Error: Socket read timed out
2017-04-13 12:50:42,711 ERROR - SqlExceptionHelper         - IO Error: Socket read timed out
2017-04-13 12:50:42,711 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] ERROR org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.list(Unknown Source)
    at com.parkwaypantai.spos.backend.common.service.impl.ClinicUserServiceImpl.list(ClinicUserServiceImpl.java:96)


Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2123)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1911)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:899)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)

Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Socket read timed out
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:347)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:106)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:324)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:268)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:190)
```

I tried getting the thread dumps also but as the server hangs so not even dumps are coming for that point of time...Please help me as I have got stuck in this case...Thanks in advance...

Comment: Post your code so we can have a look

Comment: Is the server still available *Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Socket read timed out* or is your query rying to return the whole DB?

Comment: check your query to database, it seems that your server is waiting for the db to return the results